# How to place object in relation to window browser in css/html?

Tags: html, css

How do I place an object in css to move in relation to the size of the window browser?

I tried the following types of positioning: Fixed, Absolute, and Relative. The problem I have with these are that when ever I change the size of the window browser, it stays in the same exact spot and does not move with the browser size.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: it is not clear what you are asking. can you setup a jsfiddle for what you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be defining top, bottom, left, right using `px`, so you need to use `%` instead

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/b3AJ2/)

```
<div class="hello">
  Whatever
<div>

.hello {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
}
```

Make sure if you are using `absolute` position, than wrap it inside a relative positioned container, so that it doesn't flow out in the wild

Comment: Wow that was very helpful, thanks! They dont mention to use % in tutorials online like css positioning xD. Thank you for the simple fix.

Comment: @OpMt You welcome :) and yes always wrap position absolute element inside a relative positioned container, so the absolute positioned element will be relative to it's container :)

Answer (score 0):

Without any information I'm going to assume your using pixels as your top and left? What you may want to try is:

```
.my-class {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 20%;
}
```

You can also position based on specific sizes using [@media queries in css](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2010/04/targeted-css/)